# How to groupby categories in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Well i've this movies (peliculas in spanish) so i need to groupby categories (Fiction,Scare,Drama,Suspense,Comedy,Action).

This is how my data movie looks like:

```
data Pelicula = Pelicula
  { _id          :: Int
  , _titulo      :: String
  , _alquilada   :: Bool
  , _videoclub   :: V.VideoClub
  , _categoria   :: String
  } deriving Show
```

The categories "Attribute" is a String, so if i've this list of movies:

```
pelicula1  = Pelicula 1   "Inception"                         True      V.videoclub1      "Ficcion"
pelicula2  = Pelicula 2   "Inception"                         True      V.videoclub2      "Ficcion"
pelicula3  = Pelicula 3   "Inception"                         True      V.videoclub1      "Ficcion"
pelicula4  = Pelicula 4   "The Call"                          True      V.videoclub1      "Miedo"
pelicula5  = Pelicula 5   "Frozen"                            True      V.videoclub2      "Fantasia"
pelicula6  = Pelicula 6   "Fight Club"                        False     V.videoclub2      "Accion"
pelicula7  = Pelicula 7   "Now you see me"                    False     V.videoclub1      "Suspenso"
pelicula8  = Pelicula 8   "Frozen"                            False     V.videoclub1      "Fantasia"
pelicula9  = Pelicula 9   "The Call"                          False     V.videoclub2      "Miedo"
pelicula10 = Pelicula 10  "Up"                                True      V.videoclub2      "Fantasia"
```

Movie list: `peliculas  = [pelicula1 , pelicula2, pelicula3, pelicula4, pelicula5, pelicula6, pelicula7, pelicula8, pelicula9, pelicula10]`

1) How can i group them by the ficcion (Fiction) category?
or Suspense?

2) How can i create a list of categories from the list of movies?

Comment: What do you mean by "group"? Filter?

Comment: i think filter should work (i want to see how to use the groupBy function from Data.List in this problem) but if there is a solution with filter perfect

Comment: Solution to what? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: 1) How can i group them by the ficcion (Fiction) category? or Suspense?
2) How can i create a list of categories from the list of movies?

Comment: Dude, I've asked you before: What do you mean by "group them"? Repeating your question isn't going to help.

Comment: Sorry, I have to make a VideoClub project, where i have clients,movies,videoclubs, also make functions that returns lists like that ones i asking for. So thats it. Group them like this : Fictions movies:[movies], Suspense movies [movies].. etc

Comment: ... OK, I give up. You never asked for any lists. I'm voting for closing this as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: ok i'll edit it, pls dont give up

Comment: @melpomene I believe the OP wants an equivalent of SQL "group by".

Comment: @chi OK, so how do you group by category "Fiction" in SQL?

Comment: @melpomene That makes no sense to me, I concur :) But you can group by "categoria".

Comment: thats the idea, by "categoria"

Comment: @AleMaier The confusion arises from this: either 1) you have one specific categoria at hand, e.g. "fiction" and you simply want to compute  asublist of movies having that category, or 2) you have no specific categoria at hand, and you want to compute groups -- a list of lists in which the first list contains all the movies having categoria1, the second list containing all the movies having categoria2, and so on. Asking to "group by" a specific category means nothing. I guess you want 2).

Comment: @chi i need 2 yes, but i think that's already answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code implements a utility function, which can be applied to your problem:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map -- from the "containers" library

groupToMap :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> Map.Map b [a]
groupToMap toKey =
  Map.fromListWith (++) . map (\a -> (toKey a, [a]))
```

Using that function now you can group your data easily:

```
groupPeliculas :: [Pelicula] -> Map.Map String [Pelicula]
groupPeliculas =
  groupToMap _categoria
```

Extracting a list of categories is not any less trivial:

```
peliculaCategories :: [Pelicula] -> [String]
peliculaCategories =
  map _categoria
```

If you need to get a list of unique items, do it this way:

```
import qualified Data.List as List

peliculaCategories :: [Pelicula] -> [String]
peliculaCategories =
  List.nub . map _categoria
```

But then it'll be smarter to use the `Set` datastructure for that:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

peliculaCategories :: [Pelicula] -> Set.Set String
peliculaCategories =
  foldr Set.insert Set.empty . map _categoria
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can i **group** them by the ficcion (Fiction) category? or Suspense?

Haskell base has a `groupBy` function which can be used for this purpose. You can see it's type in `ghci`:

```
λ> import Data.List (groupBy)
λ> :t groupBy
groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

Let me demonstrate that with a simpler example than your (you can use the same idea to adapt it to your code):

```
data Test = Test { id :: Int,
                   someField :: String 
                 } deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

sampleData = [Test 1 "hello", Test 2 "World", Test 3 "hello", Test 4 "World"]

groupFunction :: Test -> Test -> Bool
groupFunction t1 t2 = someField t1 == someField t2
```

The `groupFunction` will be what you will be using for performing the actual grouping. Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> groupBy groupFunction $ sortBy (\x y -> someField x `compare` someField y) sampleData 
[[Test {id = 2, someField = "World"},Test {id = 4, someField = "World"}],[Test {id = 1, someField = "hello"},Test {id = 3, someField = "hello"}]]
```

You can adapt this to your use case.

Comment: Perhaps the final example isn't the best one, since every group is a singleton. Sorting in advance should help.

Comment: @chi You are right, I didn't notice that. Using a combination of sortBy and groupBy doesn't seem nice actually.

Comment: I agree. I'd like to have a `groupSortBy` doing both in the standard libraries.